# How can I determine the position of a body in 2D space after a given time?

Tags: c++, math, physics, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to write a 2D space simulation in C++. In it, you can create a planet with mass (m) moving with a speed (v) in a direction (d) at a position (x,y). There is also one object (i.e. star) that has a gravitational pull on this planet. This object has a mass (M) and position (X,Y). I would like to create a function that returns the position of the planet after a given time t. The planet isn't necessarily in orbit but could be if speed and distance allowed for it. I know it involved Kepler's Equation but I can't figure out the exact mathematical implementation of this on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current update function does not take the star or mass into account at all.

```
double xPos, yPos, velocity, direction;
void Planet::update(int t){
    xPos += t * velocity * cos(direction / 180 * 3.14);
    yPos += t * velocity * sin(direction / 180 * 3.14);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are hoping to get from SO users. It's not clear to me whether you need help in the mathematical formulation or translating a mathematical formulation into C++ code.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have asked this in Mathematics.

Comment: @JakeP One annoying thing that you may find relevant to this question is the fact that centipede motion takes you away from algebra and more into calculus because you want the instantaneous change at a point. (Centipede motion being: Go straight for a segment then calculate how much you need to turn to make your next segment stay with an actual curve.) I've asked a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1338690/194115) but I'm having trouble getting a straight response to it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Modern_form).

> *Gm<sub>1</sub>m<sub>2</sub> / r<sup>2</sup> = F*

Once you find *F* you can just use it in a standard equation of motion:

> *F<sub>y</sub>t<sup>2</sup> / 2 + v<sub>y</sub>t + y<sub>0</sub> = y*
>   *F<sub>x</sub>t<sup>2</sup> / 2 + v<sub>x</sub>t + x<sub>0</sub> = x*